# MVVM Batch Job process file belongs to ViewModel?

Tags: wpf, c#-4.0, mvvm

I am trying to use MVVM pattern in my app. One of the things the app does is to start a batch processing job.
So I have a class file named BatchProcessing.cs. This file does not fit into the description of ViewModel. Should I put this file in ViewModel folder or put it in somewhere else?

Regards,

Comment: Its up to you, the compiler does not care about your solution folders, Place it somwhere where it makes sense to you or other developers, and IMO the ViewModel folder is the wrong place for logic only claases.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should place this file in a separate class library (in LOB apps this is usually called the Business Intelligence layer) that should be referenced from your UI project and access it from your ViewModel.

It clearly does not belong in the UI layer...

Comment: Thanks, Dean. Appreciate it.